# Proving a set of hypotheses is inconsistent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

Consider the following problem:

> Is $\{\neg p_1 \land p_2 \Rightarrow p_0, p_1 \Rightarrow (\neg p_1
> \Rightarrow p_2), p_0 \Leftrightarrow \neg p_2\}$ consistent?

I solved it in the following manner:

Observe that the third hypothesis gives $p_0 \Rightarrow \neg p_2$. At the same
time, the first gives $\neg p_1 \land p_2 \Rightarrow p_0$. This can not be
true, as will be shown below.

[image]

Observe that the hypothesis $\neg p_1 \land p_2$ is cancelled, so $Hip(D)$ is a
subset of the set we were required to evaluate.

In truth, the contradiction is no different than that following from a set such as $\{\varphi \Rightarrow \psi,
\psi \Rightarrow \neg \varphi\}$, which is clearly inconsistent, albeit
somewhat less obvious. The derivation that proves this set is contradictory
in fact follows the same structure than the one we did before:

[image]

Here too the assumption $[\varphi]_1$ is cancelled.

My confusion comes from the fact that we are not simply deriving a contradiction from the hypotheses. More precisely, we are deriving that certain assumptions that are not in the hypotheses set ($[\neg p_1 \land p_2]_1$ in the first case, $[\varphi]_1$ in the second case) imply a contradiction. I am not sure whether this is correct in proving the hypotheses set is inconsistent, precisely due to the dependence on these extraneous assumptions. I was wondering if someone could clear this out for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not agree: 2nd formula is a Tautology (Ex falso): $P \to (\lnot P \to Q)$ and thus it is always True. Thus, we are left with: $(¬p_1 ∧ p_2) ⇒ p_0$ and $p_0 ⇔ ¬p_2$. If we choose True for $p_0$ the first formula is True and nothing prevents us to choose False for $p_2$, thus satisfying also the second one.

Comment: The ND-style derivation above does not prove a contradiction, because the conclusion is not always False: it is enough to set $p_2$ to False and the formula $(\lnot p_1 \land p_2) \to \bot$ will be True.

Comment: In terms of ND, what you have proved is $(¬p_1∧p_2)⇒p_0, p_0⇒¬p_2 \vdash \lnot (¬p_1∧p_2)$